# Yii::$app->mailers->sendMultiple($messages) в цикле в паре со sleep() творит чудеса

Tags: yii2

```
foreach ($messages as $message){
    Yii::$app->mailers->send($message);
    AppHelper::addJson($mailing, 'received_emails', $to);
}
```

работает нормально, отправляет в цикле письма и делает пометки об этом в базе.
Но на хостинге есть одно из ограничений: не отправлять более 60 писем в минуту. Для этого я добавляю sleep(1.1)

```
foreach ($messages as $message){
    Yii::$app->mailers->send($message);
    AppHelper::addJson($mailing, 'received_emails', $to);
    sleep(1.1);
}
```

и происходит дублирование отправки письма, т.е. на один и тот же адрес отправляется по 2 письма.
Вопрос: как sleep() умудряется это сделать? Возможно есть нормальный способ задать нужную задержку между письмами? В идеале через как-то типа

```
->addHeader('задержка', '1')
Yii::$app->mailer->sendMultiple($messages);
```

Comment: Кто инициирует запуск скрипта отправки почты?

Comment: я, вручную запускаю рассылку

Comment: есть у кого-нибудь мысли на этот счёт?

Comment: Вы случаем не запускаете 2 и более рассылки одновременно?

Comment: нет конечно. Вообще у меня через mailer->sendMultiple($messages) всё прекрасно отправляется, но мне надо сохранять результаты отправки в базу, поэтому кручу через цикл и использую send($message) + своя функция. Порылся и нашёл afterSend() в BaseMailer ну и событие аналогичное. Как его правильно использовать?

Comment: в \yii\mail\BaseMailer::send($message) ради проверки втыкнул sleep(1.1), запустил через Yii::$app->mailers->sendMultiple($messages) - и реально одно отправляет по 2 письма!! Как так?